# Export checked item from DataBase to CSV

Tags: jquery, mysql, database, csv, export

I want to export checkbox:checked item from database to csv Using PHP & Jquery.
Everything is fine.

```
 function(data,status){
alert ();
}
```

shows exact what i want. But don't receive output as CSV.

Jquery

```
 callback: function (result) {

            if(result==true){
                $.post('exportcsv.php', {
                    export_id: id
                }, function(data){
                    location.reload();
```

MySql (exportcsv.php)

```
$myid = $_POST['export_id'];
$id=str_replace('', ',', $myid);

$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('Name', 'Price'));
$query ="Select name, price From products WHERE id IN ($id)";

$stmt=$db->prepare($query);

$stmt->execute();

    While ($row =$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
```